# Determine memory alignment of a process with C#

Tags: c#, memory, process, pinvoke, alignment

I'm writing a c# application that takes a string to any friendly process name(say 'notepad') and reads the process memory. It is fine for reading bytes but I have no idea if those are int32s, chars, bools or other types of data. One of the first steps to solving that is knowing how the data is padded. how can I determine the data alignment of the memory?

I've learned it isn't as simple as knowing the OS or processor. Different packings are supposedly possible even then: http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84519/mastering-structs-in-c/

So, is there some pinvoke I could use on the process handle to read some value or maybe an algorithm that reads some bytes and tests what it finds?

Motivation(in case someone has a better solution for my end goal): I don't want to look for potential int32 values(or any other type) by looking at relative address 0,1,2,3 and then looking at 1,2,3,4 and so on if I can help it. If memory is say 4-byte aligned, I'd be wasting a lot of effort for nothing when I could just check 0,1,2,3 and skip to 4,5,6,7.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do - but my best bet is that you're hoping to dig around the process to find a bug or get an idea what they're up to?

the best way to figure out the memory layout will be from the symbols (.pdb).  Is this an app that you've written?

Assuming not, you might consider injecting a thread and then calling MiniDumpWriteDump().  This API can dump the memory to disk where you can browse it with windbg.

The idea here will to use the Microsoft public symbols (!symfix) and then to go routing around the memory looking for whaterver you're needing.  having the symbols for the Microsoft bits will help you - with those you'll be able to figure out where threads/heaps/handles/etc are located

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The purpose of all this is entirely educational(inspired by curiosity about a utility app called dwarfTherapist). So, my goal is not to apply this memory reader to anything I can already delve into, but any process at all that has no available source code.